# Отображение шрифта Myriad Pro в Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, шрифты

В верстке используется шрифт Myriad Pro (`font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;`) , в Google Chrome надписи, сделанные им отображаются отлично от других браузеров и очень некрасиво.

В хроме
[image]

В опере, фф

[image]

В гугле ответа на вопрос можно ли поправить отображение шрифта не нашлось, есть только топики полутора-двухлетней давности что в гугл хроме были проблемы вообще с отображением этого типа шрифта, он вообще не отображался. Можно ли как-то поправить внешний вид этого шрифта?

Comment: А зачем такой хитрый шрифт? Ведь не у каждого пользователя есть он, лучше использовать привычный набор.

Comment: потому что в макете такой.

Comment: Лучше сменить, допустим у меня сейчас mint 14, все шрифты стандартные и такого нет, под виндой наверное тоже такой не у всех.

Comment: (Почему для вашей страницы странно сглаживается `Myriad Pro` в `WebKit` лично я не знаю) Тем не менее, для `non-web-safe` шрифтов однозначно стоит использовать `@font-face,` `TypeKit` или `cufon`. И не забудьте приобрести лицензию на шрифт :)

Comment: попробуйте добавить свойство ´-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased´

Comment: Передайте вашему дизайнеру, что использовать шрифт, по умолчанию предлагаемый люстрой — не самый лучший вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Посоветую в этом случае использовать cuFon, самый оптимальный вариант, так как  Myriad Pro один из платных шрифтов Adobe, можете так же [купить](https://typekit.com/fonts/myriad-pro),

Когда то давно сам мучился с этим шрифтом cuFon снял все вопросы.