# Проблема с добавлением нового шрифта

Tags: c#, winforms

В проекте решил использовать новый шрифт Myriad Pro. При выставленном размере 11 все нормально. При других размерах (меньших) буквы "покусаны". Можно ли решить эту проблему и почему так происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы про артефакт лейбла с текстом "Путь к БД", так это, очевидно, что лейблу не хватает высоты. Решение простое - увеличьте `height` или установите свойство `autosize` в `true`. По-моему, проблема может быть именно в этом.

Comment: Если бы ответ был так прост, то не задавал бы. Приложу еще один скрин, чтобы было еще понятнее.

Comment: Скрин не помешал бы, конечно, а еще лучше - из режима разработки (design-time).
Компоненты - станадартные?

Comment: В режиме разработки картинка та же. Компоненты стандартные.

Comment: С другими шрифтами (к примеру Bembo) такого нет

Comment: @BlackWitcher если шрифт бы резал контрол, то верхняя граница была бы на одном уровне

Comment: Используемые компоненты в проекте - стандартные WinForms? Или может сторонние какие? Версия студии и виндовс какая, подскажите, не помешает. И какой DPI установлен в системе? Проблема только на вашей машине? Если перенести программу на другую машину, то ситуация не меняется?

Comment: Компоненты в данной форме стандартные, но в проекте есть и сторонние, но это вряд ли что-то меняет. Версия: Ultimate 2012. ОС Windows 7 Максимальная  Service Pack1 x64.

Comment: Перенести на машину - сам проект или достаточно инсталлятор запустить на другой и глянуть?

Comment: @Александр Пузанов не проверяйте у меня то же самое

Comment: Выходит, что со шрифтом самим проблема?

Comment: Поменял свойство Unit с Point на Pixel, вроде лучше стало, все свойства отрабатывают корректно кроме Point. Я не знаю особенностей создания шрифтов, но может это баг шрифта

Comment: Вернул на Point шрифт отобразился корректно

Comment: Лучше, но это уже не 8 размер, а 6

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50514/discussion-between-user2455111-and--).

Comment: Ну, у меня лучше не стало

Comment: Похоже (и вероятнее всего, хотя утверждать не берусь на 100%) это проблема шрифта. Баги с его рендерингом [наблюдаются не только в VS](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545643), но и в браузерах, [например](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12754027/6935496). [Вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/174069/222168).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычитал, что не все шрифты малого размера выглядят красиво. (Это если коротко) Поэтому, чтобы не налажать и не мучаться - вот официальный сайт https://fonts.google.com/. Можно посмотреть как себя ведет конкретный шрифт. Без проблем можно скачать и установить. В моем варианте выбрал Open Sans как альтернативу.